# Wireless display disconnected alert stays visible

Tags: windows-10

After disconnecting from a wireless display, the following alert stays visible at the top of my screen, above all other windows:

[image: wireless display disconnected alert]

The two lines on the left, and the two buttons on the right are unreponsive to mouse manipulation, the only button that is reponsive is *Reconnect*, which will in-fact reconnect to me to the display I've disconnected from - even if someone else is already connected to it.

I also cannot drag the alert, nor does a context menu appear on right-click.

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: I've seen the same bug, but I can't remember how I got rid of it :/ As a hack, have you tried turning your wifi off and on again? Miracast works over wifi, so that may trigger a reset of the dialog pane.